# CHEF - Attempt to use relative path 'foo when current directory is outside the repository path

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When I try and run `knife upload roles` or `knife upload /roles` it gives the following error

```
cd ~/my-chef-repo
knife upload roles -n -V
INFO: Using configuration from /Users/sowen/.chef/knife.rb
ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'roles' when current directory is outside the repository path
```

My knife.rb file

```
cookbook_path            "/Users/me/my-chef-repo"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when the cookbook_path is not properly set in your knife.rb

Do the following:

Make sure you have a trailing slash in your knife.rb

```
cookbook_path            "/Users/me/my-chef-repo/"
```

Or pass in the repo path from the commandline

```
knife upload roles -n -VV --chef-repo-path /Users/me/my-chef-repo/
```

Comment: that looks like the repo path? should it not be `/Users/me/my-chef-repo/cookbooks` similar to the docs? - https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html#settings

Answer (score 0):

I found, that knife can be either case-sensitive:

https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4663

or "slash"-sensitive:

Basically, I had one slash (\) in my knife.rb, but my Windows system was producing other slash (/), and they were not matching.

Comment: Unrelated to OP's problem, and false, windows does not produce "/" as it uses backslashes. Ruby interpreter reading the `knife.rb` file would treat a backslash as an escape character and mess your path, use forward slashes in the config, chef code sanitize the paths according to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was placing the cookbook folder inside ~/.chef folder which was causing the issue. I solved it by moving the cookbook folder one directory up and updated the path in ~/.chef/knife.rb.

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbook_dir"]
```